# (Java/Junit) I set the class path, and now I cannot compile the test file in the command prompt

Tags: java, junit, classpath

Okay, I am trying to test a class with a test class using `import junit.framework.*;` and I download the Junit library and saved it with a classpath of:`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib\junit-4.8.2.j…`

I set up the CLASSPATH, and every time I try to compile the test file I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Anita\Documents\java\Project2>j… TestImage.java
TestImage.java:1: error: package junit.framework does not exist
import junit.framework.*;
^
```

Did I do something wrong in the `classpath`? I tried everything! Any suggestions on how I can finally get junit to work?

Comment: Yes, you did something wrong with your classpath. However your question makes it impossible to actually help, because we can't see what you've defined as your classpath during compilation. (And you don't "save a library with a classpath", you save it somewhere and include it on your classpath.)

Comment: Also, it's probably not a good idea to put jar files meant for use with a particular application in the jdk's sub-directories. Put them in a 'lib' directory under your application's main directory. Better yet, investigate a decent build tool, e.g. Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Try to unzip your jar to check if the contents is really there.
Also, instead setting the environment variable, try to pass the classpath as an argument, like follows:

```
javac -cp ./junit-4.8.2.jar TestImage.java
```

but instead of `./junit-4.8.2.jar`, use the full path of your jar.

Answer (score 1):

...A couple of years late...

At least in 2014, you need to `import` from `org.junit`.  The [JUnit "Getting Started" guide](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started) states "Do not use any classes in junit.framework or junit.extensions."

As an example:

```
import org.junit.*;

public class TestFoobar {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
    }

    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void thisIsIgnored() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // Code executed after each test
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

...and then run tests

```
C:\junit>dir
 Volume in drive C is L032336
 Volume Serial Number is CAB2-E609

 Directory of C:\junit

2014-10-20  06:57    <DIR>          .
2014-10-20  06:57    <DIR>          ..
2014-10-20  06:11            45,024 hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
2014-10-20  06:11           245,039 junit-4.11.jar
2014-10-20  06:57               518 TestFoobar.java
               3 File(s)        290,581 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  277,498,945,536 bytes free

C:\junit>javac -cp junit-4.11.jar TestFoobar.java

C:\junit>java -cp .;junit-4.11.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestFoobar
JUnit version 4.11
I.
Time: 0.007

OK (1 test)
```